# Quick question about subsetting via character-class

Tags: r

I think this is a super quick thing, but I figured I'd ask since I can't for the life of me remember how to do it...

Suppose, I have a data.frame (call it, `DF`) with the following headers: `"Blah"`, `"Bleh"`, and `"Meh"`.
I also have an character-class vector `foo`, with the elements being the same as the headers of `DF`.

`Blah <- rnorm(10)`
`Bleh <- runif(10)`
`Meh <- rnorm(10)`
`DF <- data.frame(Blah,Bleh,Meh)`
`foo <- c(rep("Blah",3),rep("Bleh",3),rep("Meh",3))`

I would like to do the following: Subset `DF` according to the i'th element within `foo`. I thought this--`DF$foo[1]`--would work, but it doesn't.

I know I can subset using `names` and `==`, but I think there's a much shorter (1-line) way?

Answer (score 3):

`DF$foo[1]` tries to return the first element of the column named `foo` (which doesn't exist).  You want `DF[foo[1]]`.

Comment: OY! Can't believe I didn't remember that!! Thanks Joshua!!

Answer (score 2):

```
subset(DF, select=foo[3])
              Blah
1   0.814939149951
2  -0.800644571486
3  -0.424080059851
4   1.012792429940
5   1.291888735720
6   0.642523425131
7   0.537486547429
8   0.315031122082
9  -0.296439716108
10  0.372453578695
```

Comment: This us a bit confusing because of the way the select argument works - normally you give it inquired variable names, not a variable containing quotednames

Comment: Both quoted and unquoted arguments succeed with subset. It will evaluate what is offered just as "[" does.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

`DF[ ,foo][1]`

Ah, Joshua posted while I was typing... You can aslo select regions of the columns, eg:

```
DF[1:3,foo][1]
```